# Listing the achievements unlocked by a friend

Tags: google-play-games

In [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games&hl=en), is it possible to view all the [achievements](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3129940?hl=en) unlocked by a friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the achievements wont be listed at once when you visit your friend's account(when you see their profile in the Google Play Games application). Instead when you visit their profile you get the list of games that your friend is playing/played. And you have to click each game your friend has played and compare/view the achievements with your friend's profile with your profile.